# How to find out session timeout duration?

Tags: web, session

Is there a way to find out how long does a website timeout user's session? By looking into cookie? Or is it server side controlled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the cookie contains a `Expires` field, read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age). a website could use either that .. or track the user with a persistent cookie and then decide itself what to do.

so, the answer to your question is: it depends on how the website's session management is implemented.